# Unit testing annotations?

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations

I'm asking myself how deep should I go in (unit) testing my classes.
As example, I have following simple class .

```
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path(value = "ping")
@Singleton
@PermitAll
public class PingRestService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String pingMethod(){
        return "pong";
    }

}
```

I wrote following unit test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.junit.Test;


public class PingRestServiceTest {

    PingRestService prs = new PingRestService();

    @Test
    public void testClassAnnotations(){
        assertEquals(3, prs.getClass().getAnnotations().length);

        assertTrue(prs.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class));
        assertTrue(prs.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Singleton.class));
        assertTrue(prs.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Path.class));

        assertEquals("ping", prs.getClass().getAnnotation(Path.class).value());

    }

    @Test
    public void testPingMethodAnnotations() throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException{

        Method method = prs.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("pingMethod");
        assertEquals(2, method.getAnnotations().length);

        assertTrue(method.isAnnotationPresent(GET.class));
        assertTrue(method.isAnnotationPresent(Produces.class));

        assertEquals(1, method.getAnnotation(Produces.class).value().length);
        assertEquals(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, method.getAnnotation(Produces.class).value()[0]);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPingMethod() {
        assertEquals("pong", prs.pingMethod());
    }

}
```

does it make sense? 
Or should I only test the returning string ("pong", testPingMethod), skipping all annotations tests (testClassAnnotations,testPingMethodAnnotations) ?

I think some annotations are part of a business logic (e.g. PermitAll), and therefore should be tested.

Comment: I would do an integration test on the full class that creates the webservice and tests the restful api; this should be separate from the unit tests.

Comment: If you add an extra media type to your @Produces annotation, your test breaks, yet you have not changed any logic within the method under test. Seems like a pointless test and brittle as well.

Comment: but if the test breaks, it's bad? I mean, I expect that the method produces a specific media type only. If I add another media type, I must adjust my tests. It's not a good practice? Testing something like PermitAll could be much more complicated with an Integration Test. Using the standard isAnnotationPresent method of java classes could I cover it in a single line of code.

Comment: You test if the security is implemented the way it *should* work. Live provides with surprisingly many sideeffects like configuration problems or others that can prevent that it *actually* works.
Yes, it needs more effort to configure a test that simulates the security the way it is really used. But you can see it as an investment in your know how that has a good chance to be valuable for you later on. And how much is a test worth that tests the security the way it is really used compared to a test that only checks if the security has an implementation that should lead to the desired result.

Comment: @lappo, is there no answer that works for you? Or do you still have questions?

Comment: I still have a couple of doubts about no testing annotations at unit level (writing such tests doesn't cost too much time, and it's always better than no testing at all), but I appreciate your answer and comments. Thank you!

Comment: I agree that testing the annotations is a little bit better than not testing at all. If the annotation gets lost at an automatic merge in your source code versioning software you will see it in the test. But you test no more than the existance of the line of code. And from a maintenance perspective it is not cheap as you always have to change the test if you change the code.

Comment: Yes, it makes absolutely perfect sense to test annotations. Back when XML was king developers complained about "programming in XML".  Now that we've moved all that stuff to annotations, complaints are about "programming in annotations."  Annotations are 100% essential in the correct execution of your code and so are very important to test.  What if someone changes the @Path value...you'll want to know this!  In addition, testing annotations is a great way to avoid starting frameworks during unit testing but ensure classes are still configured correctly.  Wiring JPA entities is a good example.

Comment: I think this is awesome. I came across this while doing TDD and I think it makes sense to make sure certain annotations are present and use of annotation is not an accident but deliberate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the time one tests the functionality of the code and not the way it is implemented. This is called `Black Box Testing` (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing). 
When implementing a test you should ask yourself: "What are the possible input values of the unit to test and what are the expected results?"
Now in the test you call your code with the input values and check the result with the expected one to make sure your code behaves the way you want it.
Over time you might optimize the code without wanting to change the functionality. Then you should not need to change your test. But you can re-run it to make sure it still behaves the same way. Even if it is implemented differently. Or you might make change implementation details that have side effects to the functionality you tested. Also in this case you don't need to change the test but you just need to re-run it.
In your simple case you have no input and one static output so you can just call the method and check if "pong" is returned. But real life cases that are tested are rarely that simple.

Edit: You can see the security that `@PermitAll` configures and the URL path that '@Path' configures as inputs and also test them in an integration test the way 'Boris the Spider' and 'Avi' suggested. But the other annotations are implementation specific.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion those annotations are aspects of your class and not the essence of it, its real purpose, so shouldn't be unit tested.
Maybe tomorrow you will use Spring MVC instead of JAX-RS, but your class would have the same behavior so the unit test should be the same