# JUnit integration test with parameterized annotations

Tags: java, testing, junit, annotations, integration-testing

In my integration tests I use custom annotations to start part of my application. I definitively need to use these annotations for my tests. Therefore, a typical integration test looks like this:

```
@Test
@MyAnnotation(a = MyEnum.B, b = someOtherConstant)
public void test() {
}
```

What I'd like to do is to run the tests for all enums in MyEnum. I thought about using a parameterized tests. But since the value I pass into the annotation must be constant, I think this is not an option. What other options do I have?

Comment: I am unsure what you want to test. Do you want to test the annotation, then maybe you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261501/unit-testing-annotations; or do you want to test something for all values of an enum, then I think parameterized tests are the right choice (enum value + test result).

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm trying to write a parameterized test for all values of the enum. however, I can't pass the enum into the Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a need for an annotation here.

A very simple enum:

```
package stackoverflow52828976;

public enum MyEnum
{
   A,
   B,
   C;

   public boolean isA()
   {
      return this == A;
   }
}
```

The test class:

```
package stackoverflow52828976;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

@RunWith( Parameterized.class )
public class MyEnumTest
{

   @Parameterized.Parameters
   public static Collection<Object[]> data()
   {
      final List<Object[]> list = new LinkedList<>();

      list.add(new Object[]{ MyEnum.A, true});
      list.add(new Object[]{ MyEnum.B, false});
      list.add(new Object[]{ MyEnum.C, false});

      return list;
   }


   private final MyEnum e;
   private final boolean testResult;


   public MyEnumTest
         ( final MyEnum    anEnum
         , final boolean   aTestResult
         )
   {
      this.e = anEnum;
      this.testResult = aTestResult;
   }


   @Test
   public void testIsA() throws Exception
   {
      assertEquals(testResult, e.isA());
   }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think I can get rid off my annotations? Without these annotations my tests wouldn't work anymore. The annotations are responsible for setting up the required infrastructure.

Comment: But the annotations are not related to the test of the enumeration, or am I wrong? If you have to setup something for the test, you can still use your annotation in the test, but the test of the enumeration is unrelated to this.

Comment: I think I start getting what you really what, I am not sure if this is possible at all. Can you give a minimal example (SSCCE) of what you want to do in the test with the value of the enumeration from the annotation. It is not a method parameter, we agree on that.